# Running scp when .bashrc of remote machine includes source command

Tags: scp

I cannot copy a file over scp when the remote machine .bashrc file includes **source** command to update paths and some variables. Why does it happen?

Comment: Is your user shell actually `/bin/sh`? Are you sourcing `~/.bashrc` from `~/.profile`?

Comment: Yes, my bash is /bin/sh. I asked the question wrongly. My .bashrc file includes a source command to update the paths.

Comment: The problem probably is not that .bashrc is reading in other files but that it is outputting something. This will confuse `scp`, which actually runs `ssh` to run a slightly different `scp` command on the remote system and then parses its output. If you can rewrite your .bashrc so that **nothing it runs or sources will produce output**, `scp` will probably work.

Comment: I know that scp runs when .bashrc does not source or run anything. I wonder if there is a workaround for that during login process.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should make part or all of your `.bashrc` **not** run when your shell is non-interactive.  (An `scp` is an example of a non-interactive shell invocation, unless someone has radically altered your systems.)  Then put all commands that can possibly generate output in that section of the file.

A standard way to do this in an init file is:

```bash
# Put all the commands here that should run regardless of whether
# this is an interactive or non-interactive shell.

# Example command:
umask 0027

# test if the prompt var is not set and also to prevent failures
# when `$PS1` is unset and `set -u` is used 
if [ -z "${PS1:-}" ]; then
    # prompt var is not set, so this is *not* an interactive shell
    return
fi

# If we reach this line of code, then the prompt var is set, so
# this is an interactive shell.

# Put all the commands here that should run only if this is an
# interactive shell.

# Example command:
echo "Welcome, ${USER}.  This is the ~/.bashrc file."
```

You might also see people use

```bash
[ -z "${PS1:-}" ] && return
```

instead of my more verbose `if` statement.

If you don't want to rearrange your whole file, you can also just make certain lines run only in interactive context by wrapping them like so:

```bash
if [ -n "${PS1:-}" ]; then
    echo "This line only runs in interactive mode."
fi
```

If you segregate your `.bashrc` this way, then your `scp` commands should no longer have this problem.

Comment: Good advice. This problem has been around for over 30 years, dating from BSD's `rcp` command coupled with `csh` and `.cshrc`. Hopefully, in time, `ssh` can provide an alternative way of doing `scp` that isn't affected by the remote user's shell at all.

Comment: It is very informative! It's the answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: I had this issue; but needed to return (versus exit).  When I used exit the scp didn't output; but also didn't copy files.

Comment: Your solution did not work for me (specifically in the case of resuming gnu screen), but this did:  https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13589/makes-screen-your-default-shell-without-breaking-scp-or-sftp     [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ] && [ -z "$STY" ] && screen -DRA

Comment: This explains what the problem is and how to fix it, but I'd love to know *why* it fails. What about putting an interactive command (e.g. `source` or `echo`) in a `~/.bashrc` file *causes* SCP to fail?

Comment: another way to check if shell interactive `[[ $- = *i* ]] || return`

Comment: @jvriesem `source` does not harm, but output does. The problem simply seems to be that `scp` sends not only data but also commands over the standard streams. So putting an `echo "hello"` in your .bashrc will result in `helloC0774 123 foo.txt` being transmitted, as scp sends the access pattern and size with the `C` command first if you want to transfer the file `foo.txt`. But with the leading "hello" this is no longer understandable by the receiving client.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me as well. But since my default shell is TCSH, I had to slightly edit the fix as follows (in .tcshrc):

```
if ( $?SSH_TTY ) then
    exec /bin/bash
endif
```

Just thought I would share for everyone's benefit.